# LaTex template for Medical Physics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, journal-publishing

Anyone knows where to get LaTex template for journal of Medical Physics?

http://www.medphys.org/

I found one at http://www.tobias-elze.de/latex/, but it does not seem to match the format as I downloaded from thr official website. The latest published paper are double columned.

I am new to latex, and I am really not good at creating a one from scratch. That's why I prefer to work from a template. Anyone has any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/medical-physics-example-paper/gpscvvgcjfjd#.V6jOPVUrLnA) what you want?

Comment: *Authors are expected to follow the conventional writing, notation, and illustration style prescribed in the AIP Publishing Author Resource Center.* Reading this, the usual AIP template seems to be a good idea.

Comment: The most reliable answer can be retrieved from your editor.

Comment: @heather No it does not seem like what I need.

Comment: [This page](http://medphys.peerx-press.org/html/medphys/medphys_author_instructions.html) has a [link to a template](http://medphys.peerx-press.org/html/medphys/aapmtemplate.tex) and has some [instructions for LATeX submissions](http://medphys.peerx-press.org/html/medphys/medphys_instructions.html#latex).

Comment: @alwaysask I think this is it. Can you please post your reply as answer below? I will accept it.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks for your reply. I think your replay is also acceptable. I prefer alwaysask though. But if you Johannes post yours, I can upvote it and you can get the points. Thank you so much.

Comment: @alwaysask You tracked down the stuff, can you write up an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](https://medphys.msubmit.net/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=display_auth_instructions) has a [link to a template](https://medphys.msubmit.net/images/aapmtemplate.tex) and has some [instructions for LATeX submissions](https://medphys.msubmit.net/html/medphys_instructions.html#latex).

Comment: @bers: please edit the answer for the updated links :-)